Why can't python httpd start a thread inside a python docker container?
I'm trying to run a webserver to examine a system's behaviour under load.
While looking at alternatives, I thought to try Python's webserver:
If I run the following, it works as expected:
$ sh -c 'ulimit; date>date.txt ;  python3 -m http.server' &
unlimited
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
$ curl localhost:8000/date.txt
Wed May  8 10:11:00 UTC 2024

If I try to run it within a docker container, it can't fork:
$ docker run --detach --name pyhttp -p 8000:8000 python:3 sh -c 'ulimit ; date>date.txt python3 -m http.server'
$ curl localhost:8000/date.txt
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
$ docker logs pyhttp

unlimited
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('172.18.0.1', 23904)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/socketserver.py", line 318, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/socketserver.py", line 706, in process_request
    t.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 992, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
----------------------------------------


I thought to check the versions:
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
$ docker run python:3 python3 --version
Python 3.12.3

Running the docker command with python:3.6.8 worked.
Seems this broke some time before 3.7 - I've reported an issue.
